# Adding Text to Windows Integrated Authentication Dialogue Box

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, authentication, iis-6

Is there any way to change the content of a Windows Integrated authentication dialogue box? We mostly just want to add some extra help text to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no a way to change this dialog box. It might differ among browsers as well. You could use Forms Authentication if you want to customize the login screen.

Comment: Here's a post on using Forms Authentication with Active Directory
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx